# Squaring all elements in a list

Tags: python, arrays, return

I am told to

Write a function, square(a), that takes an array, a, of numbers and returns an array containing each of the values of a squared.

At first, I had

```
def square(a):
    for i in a: print i**2
```

But this does not work since I'm printing, and not returning like I was asked.
So I tried

```
    def square(a):
        for i in a: return i**2
```

But this only squares the last number of my array. How can I get it to square the whole list?

Comment: Is this homework? Seems like it is.

Comment: yes it is, I said "I am told to ..." so I thought it was obvious. I took a few attempts on the problem also and could not come up with the format that was asked for so I came here.

Comment: Please be careful with your use of `list` and `array`; those are two different data structures.

Comment: @Akavall: note that the homework tag is now deprecated and should not be added to questions

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
def square(list):
    return [i ** 2 for i in list]
```

Or you could `map` it:

```
def square(list):
    return map(lambda x: x ** 2, list)
```

Or you could use a generator. It won't return a list, but you can still iterate through it, and since you don't have to allocate an entire new list, it is possibly more space-efficient than the other options:

```
def square(list):
    for i in list:
        yield i ** 2
```

Or you can do the boring old `for`-loop, though this is not as idiomatic as some Python programmers would prefer:

```
def square(list):
    ret = []
    for i in list:
        ret.append(i ** 2)
    return ret
```

Comment: Good that you point out a lot of methods. However, most established solutions are based on list comprehension or numpy. For performance of `map` in combination with `lambda`, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map

Comment: Thank you! I used the comprehension method. Will be looking more into that method.

Comment: "This is not as idiomatic as some Python programmers would prefer" - I completely agree, but it's worth pointing out that there are situations in which the only practical option is to append to a list. The best example I can think of is if the generator needs to 'remember' the numbers it has previously returned so as not to return duplicates or get into a cycle.

Comment: up voted for the O(1) space complexity map solution

Answer (score 36):

**Use a list comprehension (this is the way to go in pure Python):**

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [i**2 for i in l]
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Or [numpy](https://numpy.org/) (a well-established module):

```
>>> numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4])**2
array([ 1,  4,  9, 16])
```

In `numpy`, math operations on arrays are, by default, executed element-wise. That's why you can `**2` an entire array there.

Other possible solutions would be `map`-based, but in this case I'd really go for the list comprehension. It's Pythonic :) and a `map`-based solution that requires `lambda`s [is slower than LC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map).

Answer (score 9):

```
import numpy as np
a = [2 ,3, 4]
np.square(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use numpy.

```
import numpy as np
b = list(np.array(a)**2)
```

Comment: Numpy for such a trivial problem seems like overkill.

Comment: Fair point, but where you have the need to square lists, you soon need to start doing other operations with them and there is no reason re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid having to use np.array and just use array(a)**2?

Comment: @user1936752 No, because the "to the power of" function on standard arrays isn't defined. However, it's defined on `numpy` arrays, because they aren't really arrays; they are a special data type created by the `numpy` module.

Answer (score 1):

```
def square(a):
    squares = []
    for i in a:
        squares.append(i**2)
    return squares
```

Answer (score 0):

One more map solution:

```
def square(a):
    return map(pow, a, [2]*len(a))
```

Comment: Also, `itertools.repeat(2)` would work instead of creating a list of `2`s

Answer (score 0):

```
def square(a):
    squares = []
    for i in a:
        squares.append(i**2)
    return squares
```

so how would i do the square of numbers from 1-20 using the above function

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
square_list =[i**2 for i in start_list]
```

which returns

```
[25, 9, 1, 4, 16]
```

or, if the list already has values

```
square_list.extend([i**2 for i in start_list])
```

which results in a list that looks like:

```
[25, 9, 1, 4, 16]
```

*Note*: you don't want to do

```
square_list.append([i**2 for i in start_list])
```

as it literally adds a list to the original list, such as:

```
[_original_, _list_, _data_, [25, 9, 1, 4, 16]]
```

Comment: Note: `square_list.extend()` does not return anything as this is an in place operation.

Comment: @AChampion you are correct, i'll edit to make it more accurate. Also its funny to look at myself from 4 years ago talk wow