# Square a list (or array?) of numbers in Python

Tags: python, square

I'm coming from a MATLAB background and this simple operation so far seems to be extremely complicated to implement in Python, according to the answers in other stacks. Typically, most answers use a for loop.

The best I've seen so far is

```
import numpy
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
b = list(numpy.array(start_list)**2)
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Why not just use  a numpy array altogether?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I do not think this question is about numpy (even though it was tagged as such). I think that the numpy way was the most compact one found by the OP

Comment: I added the `numpy` tag, the original question imports `numpy` and uses `numpy.array`, also the OP says to be coming from a MATLAB background, seems fitting IMO.

Comment: @user16538. the OP is already using numpy and seem to be doing numeric calculations so it is definitely related to numpy and it would make a lot more sense to just use numpy arrays unless there is some specific reason why they cannot.

Comment: The suggested duplicate I linked is valid for _vanilla_ Python answers (list comprehension, map + lambda) etc only. It is not valid for `numpy`.

Comment: NumPy is definitely the tool that you need to do Matlab-like work in Python. I found https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html very helpful when I made the switch.

Comment: I'm learning Python guys, and it's only been a week. But still it surprises me that while MATLAB can simply do x.^2, there isn't a simple thing like that in Python.

Comment: Use JUST this: `myarray ** 2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most readable is probably a list comprehension:

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
b = [x**2 for x in start_list]
```

If you're the functional type, you'll like `map`:

```
b = map(lambda x: x**2, start_list)  # wrap with list() in Python3
```

Answer (score 7):

<sub>Note: Since we already have duplicates for the [vanilla Python, list comprehensions and map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555443/squaring-all-elements-in-a-list) and that I haven't found a duplicate to square a **1D numpy array**, I thought I'd keep my original answer that uses `numpy`</sub>

### `numpy.square()`

If you're coming from MATLAB to Python, you are definitely correct to try to use numpy for this. With numpy you can use [`numpy.square()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.square.html) which returns the element-wise square of the input:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
>>> np.square(start_list)
array([25,  9,  1,  4, 16])
```

### `numpy.power()`

There is also a more generic [`numpy.power()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.power.html)

```
>>> np.power(start_list, 2)
array([25,  9,  1,  4, 16])
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
squares = [x*x for x in start_list]
```

Note: as a minor optimization, doing `x*x` is faster than `x**2` (or `pow(x, 2))`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use list comprehension:

```
[i**2 for i in start_list]
```

Or if you're using `numpy` you could use [`tolist`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLhvrP3pzLAhUpD5oKHVlODx4QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy-1.10.0%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.ndarray.tolist.html&usg=AFQjCNH3UQFJfTHefZlFW-BCdHH9vqV7pA&bvm=bv.115339255,d.bGs) method:

```
In [180]: (np.array(start_list)**2).tolist()
Out[180]: [25, 9, 1, 4, 16]
```

Or [`np.power`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6qPvF3pzLAhUKG5oKHR7MDfwQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy-1.10.0%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.power.html&usg=AFQjCNGN2kR-HxbHF-3HCN4ANNd8H7jtAA&bvm=bv.115339255,d.bGs):

```
In [181]: np.power(start_list, 2)
Out[181]: array([25,  9,  1,  4, 16], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: squares = [x*x for x in nums] 
         return sorted(squares)