# How to modify the value of index while trying to fecth it?

Tags: python

For example there is a list called Demo_list.

```
Demo_list = [4,5,6,7]
```

If i give

```
Demo_list[0]
```

we will get value as 4.

But if i gave only Demo_list[0] i want to get square of that value and the list should not be modified.

Is it possible?

Comment: `Demo_list[0] ** 2` ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do that in several ways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squaring all elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555443/squaring-all-elements-in-a-list)

Comment: I already said that i have to give only Demo_list[0] then i should get the square of that. i don't want to give any like ur following answers. I just want to give Demo_list[0], i.e; i want to override internal functions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

```
variable = Demo_list[0]**2
```

The code above won't modify the list.

Comment: I already said that i have to give only Demo_list[0] then i should get the square of that. i don't want to give any like ur following answers. I just want to give Demo_list[0], i.e; i want to override internal functions

Answer (score 0):

```
demo_list = [4, 6, 7, 8]
for i in range (len(demo_list)):
    j = demo_list[i] * demo_list[i]
    print j
```

May be you are looking something like that..

Comment: I already said that i have to give only Demo_list[0] then i should get the square of that. i don't want to give any like ur following answers. I just want to give Demo_list[0], i.e; i want to override internal functions

Comment: means you want to use index value as a square but index should not be modified..
i don't think it is a good idea because when you going to access its value without manipulation it only shows what value it hold.

Comment: Ok thanks but i know that, so only i asked about overriding  internal function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the < math > function

```
import math
print ( math.pow(demo[0],2)
```

where, 2 is the power that you want to raise the value in demo[0].

Edit (Inheriting from the collections, and overriding the abstract list methods , in your case (**getitem**),that you wish to modify).

`import collections
class MyList(collections.MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.list=list()
        self.extend(list(args))
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.list)
    def __getitem__(self,i):
        return (self.list[i]**2)
    def __delitem__(self,i):
        del self.list[i]
    def __setitem__(self,i,v):
        self.list[i]=v
    def insert(self,i,v):
        self.list.insert(i,v)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.list)`

**Note:** When you override these abstract methods, you need to define your list, with the type, you declared in this class. i.e.,

`demo_list=MyList(1,2,3,4)
demo_list[1]`

**Output** : 4

Comment: I already said that i have to give only Demo_list[0] then i should get the square of that. i don't want to give any like ur following answers. I just want to give Demo_list[0], i.e; i want to override internal functions

Comment: Please refer to the _Edit_ section in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```
#For complete list
SqrtList = [x**2 for x in Demo_list]
#For single element
Sqrtvariable = Demo_list**2
```

Comment: look at the comments first, for remaining answers and can't u understand the question?